# How to make child <ul> element to take its parent <li> width

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu consists of ul nested in another ul's list item position absolute.
indeed I want the child ul that represents the dd menu to take its parent li width but it takes its grandparent's ul width instead.
changing the position to relative will disrupt the li style/order don't know why.

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav>ul.nav_list {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 40px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav>ul>li>div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D88B1D;
  padding: 8px 9.5px 2px;
  transition: border-bottom .1s;
  line-height: 22px;
}

nav>ul>li>div:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #D88B1D;
}

.first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 242px;
}

li.dropdown {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #42526e;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover>div.first {
  border: none;
}

nav>ul>li>ul.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: gold;
  z-index: 99;
}

li.dropdown:hover>ul.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover>div.first>a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_list">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <div class="first">
        <a href="#">All Catgories</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li> <a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><a href="#">Shop by brand</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><a href="#">Online Exclusive</a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Set the child `ul`'s width to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) an element relatively to its parent, you need the parent to have it's own [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).  So the parent becomes an `offsetParent` -- its offset boundaries will be used for positioning.

In your case, you have to set `position: relative` to `li.dropdown`.
Then, on `ul.dropdown-content`, set `left: 0; right:0;` to stretch it between left and right boundaries so it takes 100% of parent's width:

```css
nav>ul.nav_list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 40px;
}

nav>ul>li {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav>ul>li>div {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #D88B1D;
  padding: 8px 9.5px 2px;
  transition: border-bottom .1s;
  line-height: 22px;
}

nav>ul>li>div:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #D88B1D;
}

.first {
  text-align: center;
  width: 242px;
}

li.dropdown {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #42526e;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover>div.first {
  border: none;
}

nav>ul>li>ul.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right:0; left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: gold;
}

li.dropdown:hover>ul.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover>div.first>a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_list">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <div class="first">
        <a href="#">All Catgories</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
        <li> <a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><a href="#">Shop by brand</a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><a href="#">Online Exclusive</a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks alot but you could have done me an extra favor by telling me what you had done.
so the fix is to position the parent relative.

Comment: @Odai_, thank you, I've updated my answer with explanation.